# Chipmunk2D repeatability

Tags: ios, chipmunk

I am currently part way through developing my first game with chipmunk2D on the iOS platforms.

One problem I have encountered however is the lack of repeatability within the chipmunk environment. For example, I can have a fairly simple (<20 blocks) setup and yet every time physics is applied to the body's they react in slightly different ways. The ways they react are never violently different yet they are different enough to the point where it is game breaking for me.

When creating the chipmunk bodys/shapes/spaces I am including size, mass, moment,  friction, and elasticity. I believe I am including everything there.

Does chipmunk use some randomization in its physics code? If not (or even if it does) What is the best way to fix this randomization

Answer (score 0):

http://chipmunk-physics.net/release/ChipmunkLatest-Docs/#cpShape-Misc

> Chipmunk keeps a counter so that every new shape is given a unique
>   hash value to be used in the spatial index. Because this affects the
>   order in which the collisions are found and handled, you can reset the
>   shape counter every time you populate a space with new shapes. If you
>   don’t, there might be (very) slight differences in the simulation.

So, reset the counter before each simulation, and you should have better reproductibility.

Comment: I found that the cause of this problem was the time step being used. Physics was being updated on a frame-to-frame basis, however once physics was decoupled from the frames and updated independently there was a drastic increase in repeatability. The physics simulations are now, as far as I can tell, 100% repeatable and also predictable. Thank you for your suggestion though!